# Why xilinx use a pointer to store data as array?

Tags: c, arm, xilinx

I take a look at the [AXI-DMA example](https://github.com/Xilinx/embeddedsw/blob/master/XilinxProcessorIPLib/drivers/axidma/examples/xaxidma_example_simple_poll.c) from xilinx and I get stuck at this point in `XAxiDma_SimplePollExample`

```
for(Index = 0; Index < MAX_PKT_LEN; Index ++) {
        TxBufferPtr[Index] = Value;

        Value = (Value + 1) & 0xFF;
}
```

The variable `TxBufferPtr` is a pointer, pointing on the memory address `TX_BUFFER_BASE`

```
u8 *TxBufferPtr;
TxBufferPtr = (u8 *)TX_BUFFER_BASE ;
```

Why do they use a pointer to store data with a loop? I have learned, that I should use an array to initialize the memory and use the start address of this array. So my example will look like this

```
u8 TxBufferPtr[MAX_PKT_LEN];
for(Index = 0; Index < MAX_PKT_LEN; Index ++) {
        TxBufferPtr[Index] = Value;

        Value = (Value + 1) & 0xFF;
```

How do xilinx avoid that other data may be placed in range of the pointer address + the loop range, so that the loop will overwrite this data?
Is there any trick when I use this or is it just "bad" code and use of pointer?

Comment: `TxBufferPtr = (u8 *)TX_BUFFER_BASE ;` and `u8 TxBufferPtr[MAX_PKT_LEN];` are two different memory locations. So your example code does not achieve what author is achieving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a huge difference between the two code examples.

Your code, i.e.

```
u8 TxBufferPtr[MAX_PKT_LEN];
```

will allocate memory for the array. This will be `MAX_PKT_LEN` u8 typically reserved on a stack.

This code:

```
u8 *TxBufferPtr;
TxBufferPtr = (u8 *)TX_BUFFER_BASE ;
```

does **not** allocate memory for the array. The code assumes that `TX_BUFFER_BASE` is the address of some memory that has already been allocated/reserved for the program.

If you are on some embedded system without MMU it can be a direct memory mapped region to some HW component inside the FPGA. In small simple embedded systems it's normal to map HW components using pointers to fixed addresses. The FPGA designer will give you the value of `TX_BUFFER_BASE` as it is the FPGA designer that decides how the memory space will be used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I found a explanation too. Please take a look at chapter 4 of https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf.
So xilinx set the pointer to the start address for the region for interconnect masters inside the DDR. I think that my solution with the array will be placed in the cache of the ARM. Or is there another region where an ARM can store the array?

Comment: @Kampi well, I'm not in to the details of that specific processor. The typical implementation is that a stack is used for variables like that, i.e. variables with automatic storage duration. In any case - variables are not allocated in the cache. The variables may be cached for a while but they are allocated else where. The cache is just a mirror of some other memory area.

Comment: thank you again. I will check it with my debugger. But this missunderstanding of the pointer is solved. And as a bonus I know why the DMA doesn´t work when I want to use a specific array.